# Creating a chromecast player sheet in pychromecast

Tags: python, chromecast, android-tv

The purpose of the program was to get links to videos through parsing and writing to csv, and then play them in chromecast. The way to switch the video turned out only by changing the sound in Android TV, as I found no other solution.

Here is the code itself:

```
import csv
import pychromecast
import time


# Loading Links
def load_videos():
    with open('videos.csv', newline='') as File:
        reader = csv.reader(File)
        videos_url = []
        for row in reader:
            videos_url.append(row)
        return videos_url


# Playing video on TV
def play_chromecast(url):
    # List chromecasts on the network, but don't connect
    services, browser = pychromecast.discovery.discover_chromecasts()

    # Shut down discovery
    pychromecast.discovery.stop_discovery(browser)

    # Discover and connect to chromecasts named B866
    chromecasts, browser = pychromecast.get_listed_chromecasts(friendly_names=["B866"])
    #print(chromecasts)
    # print([cc.device.friendly_name for cc in chromecasts])

    cast = chromecasts[0]
    # Start worker thread and wait for cast device to be ready
    cast.wait()
    #print(cast.status)

    mc = cast.media_controller
    mc.play_media(url, 'video/mp4')
    mc.block_until_active()
    # print(mc.status)

    mc.pause()
    time.sleep(5)
    mc.play()

    # Shut down discovery
    pychromecast.discovery.stop_discovery(browser)


# Check the transition to the next or previous
def status_volume_video():
    try:
        chromecasts, browser = pychromecast.get_listed_chromecasts(friendly_names=["B866"])
        #print(chromecasts)
        cast = chromecasts[0]
        cast.wait()
        #print(cast.status.volume_level) # test
        return cast.status.volume_level
    except:
        return None


# Basic code
videos_url = load_videos()

cnt_select = 4 # Video where to start
play_chromecast(videos_url[cnt_select][0]) # First launch
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    status_next_or_previous = status_volume_video()
    if status_next_or_previous == 0.3333333432674408:
        if not (cnt_select + 1 > len(videos_url)):
            cnt_select += 1
            play_chromecast(videos_url[cnt_select][0])
            #print('Going Forward')
    elif status_next_or_previous == 0.20000000298023224:
        if not (cnt_select - 1 < 0):
            cnt_select -= 1
            play_chromecast(videos_url[cnt_select][0])
            #print('Going Backwards')
```

The problem is that after a while an error occurs in my code:

```
[B866(192.168.0.20):8009] Failed to connect to service ServiceInfo(type='mdns', data='B866-72c0f41ce357952c2f2cbef5a1283fb7._googlecast._tcp.local.'), retrying in 5.0s
```

This error occurs after some time, and after several such errors the device cannot be connected to chromecast until you reboot the device.

1. How can you solve this error problem.
2. Is there a better solution for switching video.